# R I have a dataframe that has been ordered desc by freq how do I get ggplot to show the freq in descending order, it shows by col name instead

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with station_name.
I have ordered the data frame by station_name frequency.
There is some extra debug code in here.

````
```{r}
   df <- filter(df_clean_distances, start_station_name != "NA" )
   d <-df %>% select( start_station_name) %>%
   group_by(start_station_name) %>%
   summarize( freq = n())
   head( d$freq )
   dput(head(d))
   d2 <- d[ order(-d$freq),]
   head( d2 )
   #plot freq
   ggplot(d2, aes( x=start_station_name, y= freq)) + 
       geom_bar( stat = "identity") +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
       ylim( c(0,35000))
```
````

I can see that the data frame is ordered descending, I even added an extra order() to make sure I was getting descending.

````
```{r}
   structure(list(start_station_name = c("Streeter Dr & Grand Ave", 
   "Clark St & Elm St", "Lake Shore Dr & Monroe St", "Theater on the Lake", 
   "Lake Shore Dr & North Blvd", "Wells St & Concord Ln"), freq = c(35200L, 
   32266L, 29748L, 29561L, 26947L, 25053L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
   ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```
````

But when I run it through ggplot I get this

[image]

How can I tell ggplot to keep the order of descending so that the chart is a smooth left to right descending plot?

Comment: `ggplot(d2, aes( x=reorder(start_station_name,-freq), y= freq)) + 
  geom_bar( stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  ylim( c(0,35000))
`

Comment: perfect, not sure why i did not think of that? oh yeah, self taught in R. Thank you again @RonakShah